# Return multiple elements from a function number property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way i can return multiple elements from a function based off a number property that it ingests? For example: I have an element of a coin, which is just a `<div className="coin"></div>"` and I'd like to have a function where I can say `{displayCoins(5)}`, and the param it takes is the number of coins to return.

What I've tried so far is the following

```
const displayCoins = (numberOfCoins) => {
  let elCoin = document.createElement('div')
  elCoin.className = "coin" 
  return elCoin * numberOfCoins 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return multiple elements you can return an array of them. You don't need to create DOM elements manually with `document.createElement('div')`, you can simply create them, or template them specifically, in JSX.

```
const displayCoins = (numberOfCoins) => {
  return [...Array(numberOfCoins).keys()].map(el => (
    <div key={el} className="coin">
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you and that also makes sense to use an array and then map out too! Will select as the answer once it allows me.